# Custom tooltip in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i have made tooltip in AngularJS using this code. I want to change the background of my tooltip. I don't want black background of my tooltip content. Also i want to change the shape of tooltip. How to do this? i tried some css codes but its not giving desird result.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
});
```

```css
.round-button {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: #ff9900;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.round-button:hover {
    background: #cccc00
;
}

.zoomInInfinite {
 animation: zoomInInfinitef 1s;
 -webkit-animation: zoomInInfinitef 1s infinite;
 -moz-animation: zoomInInfinitef 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes zoomInInfinitef {
 from {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
}
 50% {
 opacity: 1;
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomInInfinitef {
 from {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
}
 50% {
 opacity: 1;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <button type="button" class="round-button zoomInInfinite" 
          data-toggle="tooltip" 
          tooltip="this is my tooltip"
          tooltip-placement="right" >
         
      </button>
          
    </div>

    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `tooltip-class` and customize tooltips you need to update `ui-bootstrap-tpls` to at least 13.0 version.

Please, follow the links and compare the tooltip docs of the versions [0.12](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.1/#/tooltip) and [0.13](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.0/#/tooltip)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fk8axjk3/) is the JSFiddle example of the customization

Answer (score 1):

Technically, tooltip directive allows you to setup almost anything starting from class and even set your own template. see docs: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip.

Once you set your class, for example, your are more than welcome to define anything you want for it.
But, I would not suggest overriding the definitions of bootstrap provided classes. You will create more problems with it for yourself.